# Raspberry Pi - Firestore timestamp issue

Tags: python, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi3

So in my project, I'm trying to send a timestamp to my firestore database. When I tested my datetime in my python code it would give me the right date and time, after sending the data to firestore, the timestamp data in the database is always +8 hours from the current time

from 2018-05-20 07:11:19.833275 to 2018-05-20 15:11:19.833275

everything else is correct, even the timezone, only except for the hour. Our time zone btw is UTC+8.
I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from google.cloud import firestore
from firebase_admin import firestore
import datetime, sys

now = datetime.datetime.now()

# Use a service account
cred = credentials.Certificate('*some key*')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
path = db.collection("*somepath*")

doc_ref = path.document()
doc_ref.set({
    'date': now,
    'rate': 60,
    'used': 1
})


print ("current: %s" %now)
```

Comment: Why are you getting `now` and then passing `datetime.datetime.now()`?

Comment: sorry, let me edit that. I forgot to change that

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For a more consistent timestamp, consider using the Firestore `SERVER_TIMESTAMP` constant:

```
doc_ref.set({
    'date': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
    'rate': 60,
    'used': 1
})
```

https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/firestore/constants.html

You can then convert your timestamp client-side, if you need to.